# Should I clean iMac fan ducts?

Tags: imac

Should I try to clean the fan ducts at the top and bottom of my five year old iMac? I have seen people say vacuuming or blowing air may mess up the innards.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced some memory in my friend's iMac of 3 year old recently and there was loads of dust on the modules. I blew the dust off the modules but didn't go in to major cleaning as it wasn't my machine. However with my own machine I would be reluctant blowing the dust off the inside of the iMac, but putting a vacuum cleaner at a very low speed shouldn't be harming much (provided the iMac is fully disconnected from the power socket.

Hope this helps.  All the best!

Comment: Vacuum cleaner == static electricity discharge == fried circuit board. Compressed air is safer.

Answer (score 0):

The way to properly clean it is to take it apart.
If you're not confident to do that, take it to a professional.

Blowing at it with a can of compressed air won't hurt - but it won't be anything like thorough either.

Vacuum cleaners are too risky, they build up static as part of their action & a discharge through any delicate component is likely to kill it.

Comment: Although there must be a YouTube video on how to do that, I am going to pass on that. And, I am flirting with getting one of the new 4K Retina models anyway. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Anyway, right now I am flirting with getting one of the new 4K iMacs.